# On click for child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, font-awesome

I want to trigger an on click event for my `<i>` tag. I added an ID to it but if i try use:

```
$("#delete-playlist-song").on("click", function() {
    console.log("in"); //doesnt trigger
});
```

It won't trigger so I want to try a different approach? Something like:

```
$("master-playlist-entries").find("i.pl-action").on("click", function() {
    console.log("in"); //Won't work
});
```

My HTML code:

```
<ul id="master-playlist-entries" class="database">
<li id="db-" track-name="James Darren -  Goodbye Cruel World" data-path="http://example.com/Cruel%20World.mp3" class="active">
<i style="display:none;" class="fa fa-bars db-action" title="Actions" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal"></i>
<i id="delete-playlist-song" class="fa fa-times pl-action" title="Remove Song From Playlist"></i>
<i class="fa fa-music db-icon"></i><span class="sn"> Goodbye Cruel World</span> <span class="bl">James Darren</span></li>
</ul>
```

What I did try was an onclick event to call a function which worked but you see, I want to grab the data-path information and pass it to that function so I can use: `$(this).attr("data-path")` which will return a different link each time for different `li`.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Your original code works fine in an isolated example, so I suspect the problem is not shown by the example above. Please show the rest of the code and a larger HTML example (e.g. if it has multiple options).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code works in a one item snippet, https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/6qhhyxs7/ so I have to guess as your example is incomplete:

It is not shown, but I would guess you have multiple `<i>` elements with the same id (e.g. `id="delete-playlist-song`). If that is the case it simply will not find any except the first one as browsers use a fast-lookup cache which can only have one element stored against each ID value. IDs must be unique on a HTML page to work property.

Switch to using classes instead and use a delegated event handler.
https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/6qhhyxs7/1/

e.g.

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-playlist-song', function() {
  $(this).closest('li').slideUp();
});
```

Notes:

- You should connect delegated event handlers to a non-changing ancestor element, but `document` is the best default if nothing else is close. Do not use `body` as it has a bug to do with styling that can cause mouse events to not fire. Use `document` as your friendly backup as it also exists before DOM ready.

Comment: Accepted as i learnt something! I didnt think using a class would be the effective way but i edited my design and now works off this information! Thanks.

Comment: @irishwill200: On modern browsers class-based jQuery selectors are almost as fast as ID selectors. They are optimised for class and ID access.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your html is added *dynamically* - so register the click listener *dynamically* using this:

```
$("body").on("click", "#delete-playlist-song", function() {
```

And for getting the attribute `data-path` you can use `$(this).closest('li').attr("data-path")` inside the listener.

See a demo below:

```js
$("body").on("click", "#delete-playlist-song", function() {
  console.log($(this).closest('li').attr("data-path"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<ul id="master-playlist-entries" class="database">
  <li id="db-" track-name="James Darren -  Goodbye Cruel World" data-path="http://example.com/Cruel%20World.mp3" class="active">
    <i style="display:none;" class="fa fa-bars db-action" title="Actions" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal"></i>
    <i id="delete-playlist-song" class="fa fa-times pl-action" title="Remove Song From Playlist"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-music db-icon"></i><span class="sn"> Goodbye Cruel World</span>  <span class="bl">James Darren</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The original actually works in isolation, so the problem is not shown by the question.

Comment: Worked Great!! Thanks a million

Comment: @irishwill200: That should not have solved the problem as you likely have duplicate IDs. Delegated events using ID selectors are seldom a good idea and indicate you have more than one issue present.

Comment: You are right, if there are *multiple* `id`s then there will be issue with *duplicate* `id`s...

Comment: @GoneCoding I do indeed have duplicate id's. Is that the issue? See i create the elements on the fly. It loads from a music library and pushes the data. As for why i use the same id, might not be the best way but i wanted to some how be able to access information needed. So if i click the `<li>` i want it to return the data-path for that element clicked. If there is a better approach that would be great!

Comment: @irishwill200: Yes. That is a serious problem. Explanation added.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Sadly i must accept the other answer now since it solves the id issue etc. Thanks @kukkuz though for the answer!